# how split an array to smaller array and keep other columns unchaned?

Tags: pyspark

How I can split an array to smaller part and keep other columns unchanged?

suppose I have column `loc` I wanna split it with respect of `" "`. whatever is between `" "`  is a new array.

example:

```
loc                                                    name
["345 canada", "60 bagh ave", "450 seelon st"]        meta
["457 ghaem shahr, vancouver,ca"]                      meta2
["this is bad", "560 nepal rd, west van, ca"]          meta3
```

output:

```
loc                                                     name
["345 canada"]                                          meta
["60 bagh ave"]                                          meta
["450 seelon st"]                                        meta
["457 ghaem shahr, vancouver,ca"]                        meta2
["this is bad"]                                          meta3
["560 nepal rd, west van, ca"]                           meta3
```

Comment: Can you provide schema of input data as assuming loc is already array type column you can use explode(loc) to get required output

Comment: explode dosn't return array, it returns string

Answer (score 0):

Try explode, Hope this helps

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
    df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
            (["345 canada", "60 bagh ave", "450 seelon st"] , "meta"),  # create your data here, be consistent in the types.
            (["457 ghaem shahr, vancouver,ca"]   , "meta2"),
          (["this is bad", "560 nepal rd, west van, ca"],"meta3" )
        ],
        ["loc", "name"]  # add your column names here
    )
    df2 = df.select(df.name,explode(df.loc))
    
    df2.show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: explode returns string not array. I want the updated column to be array type

Comment: @user15649753 will explicit casting to array work then? something like 
df2 = df.withColumn("exp_loc",explode(df.loc)).withColumn("exp_loc",F.array("exp_loc"))

Answer (score 0):

Lets use higher order functions to create list of list within loc and then explode;

```
df.withColumn('x', expr('explode(transform(loc,(x,i) -> array(x)))')).show(truncate=False)
```